# Можно ли средствами C# получить информацию о кластере?

Tags: c#, cluster

Можно ли средствами C# получить информацию о кластере?
Например получить список ролей и их ресурсы?
Если можно - скиньте ссылку почитать как это сделать.

Пробовал так, но получаю
`System.Managment.ManagmentException: Invalid class`

```
string clusterName = "app-server.local";
string custerGroupResource = "cluster.server.local";

ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions
{
    Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy
};

ManagementScope s = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + clusterName, options);

ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("Mscluster_Clustergroup.Name='" + custerGroupResource + "'");

using (ManagementObject clrg = new ManagementObject(s, p, null))
{
    clrg.Get();
    Console.WriteLine(clrg["Status"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выкладываю свое решение.
Получение ресурсов, остановка и запуск ресурсов.

```
public class ClusterManager
{
    private readonly string ClusterName;
    private readonly string ClusterNamespace;
    private ManagementScope Scope;
    private readonly ConnectionOptions Options;

    public ClusterManager(string clusterName, string clusterNamespace, string user, string password)
    {
        ClusterName = clusterName;
        ClusterNamespace = clusterNamespace;

        Options = new ConnectionOptions
        {
            Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
            Username = user,
            Password = password
        };
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        Scope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{ClusterName}\root\{ClusterNamespace}", Options);
        Scope.Connect();
    }

    public ManagementObject GetResource(string name)
    {
        string wmiClassName = "MSCluster_Resource";

        ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass(Scope, new ManagementPath(wmiClassName), null);
        managementClass.Get();
        ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = managementClass.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementBaseObject obj in objectCollection)
        {
            ManagementObject resource = (ManagementObject) obj;

            if (resource["Name"].ToString() == name)
            {
                return resource;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void TakeOffline(ManagementObject resource)
    {
        resource.InvokeMethod("Takeoffline", null, null);
    }

    public void BringOnline(ManagementObject resource)
    {
        resource.InvokeMethod("Bringonline", null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730133/programmatically-detect-windows-cluster-configuration)) и не забудьте подключить библиотеку System.Management в проект.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace  MyNamespace
{
public class ClusterAdmin
{
    [MTAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        string clusterName = "MyCluster"; // cluster alias
        string custerGroupResource = "FS_Resource1"; // Cluster group name
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Username = "ClusterAdmin"; //could be in domain\user format
        options.Password = "HisPassword";

        // Connect with the mscluster WMI namespace on the cluster named "MyCluster"
        ManagementScope s = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + clusterName + "\\root\\mscluster", options);
        ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("Mscluster_Clustergroup.Name='" + custerGroupResource + "'");

        using (ManagementObject clrg = new ManagementObject(s, p, null))
        {
            // Take clustergroup off line and read its status property when done
            TakeOffLine(clrg);
            clrg.Get();
            Console.WriteLine(clrg["Status"]);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); // Sleep for a while

            // Bring back online and get status.
            BringOnLine(clrg);
            clrg.Get();
            Console.WriteLine(clrg["Status"]);
        }
    }
    static void TakeOffLine(ManagementObject resourceGroup)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject outParams =
        resourceGroup.InvokeMethod("Takeoffline", null, null);
    }
    static void BringOnLine(ManagementObject resourceGroup)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject outParams =
        resourceGroup.InvokeMethod("Takeoffline", null, null);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: в чем отличие-то?

Comment: В TakeOffline & BringOnLine

Comment: зачем нужны эти методы, если до них даже дело не доходит?